# Firebase Messaging com Django

Tags: django, firebase, push-notification, service-worker

Eu estou um bom tempo ja apanhando com isso. Depois de horas e dias eu consegui enxergar uma luz no fim do túnel.

Eu estou utilizando um plugin para o Django, este aqui: https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django

No meu INDEX.HTML tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXX"
  };
  var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var messaging = firebase.messaging(app);
  messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
  console.log('Notification permission granted.');
  return messaging.getToken();
})
.then(function(token) {
  console.log(token); // Display user token
})
.catch(function(err) { // Happen if user deney permission
  console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});

messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
        console.log('onMessage',payload);
})
</script>
```

Não sei onde estou errando, passei a documentação, segui todos os tutoriais que vi nos resultados do Google. Chega a aparecer o TOKEN do usuário, eu chego a enviar uma mensagem e aparece no meu devtools apenas uma mensagem:

```
Service Worker was updated because "Update on reload" was checked in the DevTools Application panel.
```

Toda vez que eu envio um push aparece isso, porém push mesmo nada. Eu adicionei um device nesse plugin que estou usando mas tem um campo que não entendi.

O campo **Registration Token** eu adicionei o token gerado do usuário. Tem outro campo chamado **Device ID (Unique device identifier)**. Deixei em branco pois não sei como capturar isso.

Alguem me da uma ajuda por favor? Eu teria que fazer funcionar com Django, não rola um NodeJS não.

Obrigado desde já.